# How to configure spring to use External LDAP Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am learning about Spring Security to LDAP server, right now i am trying to make spring authenticate to ldap server. However, spring always uses the embedded server  `ldap://127.0.0.1:33389/dc=springframework,dc=org` instead of my `ldap://localhost:389/dc=localdomain,dc=local`. I'm trying to configure it using `application.properties` See below my spring configuration.

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Loading Global Auth Configuration");
         auth
            .ldapAuthentication();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Configuring HTTP Security.");
        // Configure Web Security
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // disable page caching
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Configuring Web Security HTTP Security.");
        // AuthenticationTokenFilter will ignore the below paths
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
                "/auth"
            );
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
#Ldap Info
spring.ldap.urls=ldap://localhost:389
spring.ldap.anonymous-read-only=true
spring.ldap.username=ldapadm
spring.ldap.password=root123
spring.ldap.base=ou=People,dc=localdomain,dc=local
```

Tried using above `application.properties`, still does not work.

application.properties

```
#Ldap Info
ldap.urls=ldap://localhost:389
ldap.base.dn=dc=localdomain,dc=local
ldap.username=cn=ldapadm,dc=localdomain,dc=local
ldap.password=root123
ldap.user.dn.pattern =uid={0}
```

I also tried above properties, still does not work.

```
2018-09-04 00:05:31.515  INFO 9948 --- [           main] s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource :  URL 'ldap://127.0.0.1:33389/dc=springframework,dc=org', root DN is 'dc=springframework,dc=org'
2018-09-04 00:05:31.516  INFO 9948 --- [           main] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource    : Property 'userDn' not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operations
2018-09-04 00:05:31.523  WARN 9948 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator@3bc735b3 of type class org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator
2018-09-04 00:05:31.526  INFO 9948 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

for both settings in `application.properties`, i always get this on my server log

Can anyone make sense of these? i am trying to make it read the `application.properties` but it always uses the embedded ldap in spring

Answer (score 2):

You can follow a similar approach as in [LDAP Authentication with Spring Boot](https://medium.com/@lejinkr/ldap-authentication-with-spring-boot-7b2d3fd08277)

In application.properties.

```
ldap.urls=ldap://localhost:389/dc=localdomain,dc=local
```

In your WebSecurityConfig

```
 @Value("${ldap.urls:ldap://127.0.0.1:33389/dc=springframework,dc=org}")
  private String ldapUrls;


     @Override
     public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth
     .ldapAuthentication()
     .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
     .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
     .contextSource()
     .url(ldapUrls)
     .and()
     .passwordCompare()
     .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
     .passwordAttribute("adminpassword");
     }
```

Please note that actual parameters(userDnPatterns etc...) that may be changed according to your LDAP config, i just pointed out how you can configure your LDAP config to connect to an external LDAP

Comment: ohh why can't spring `spring.ldap.url` detect this on `application.properties`? i mean without explicitly specifying in via `@Value`

Comment: I had a look at the code and it seems that they are using builder pattern for setting config values, not reading from property files. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java#L315

Comment: ohh i see, who then uses `spring.ldap.url`? i test that configuration via `LdapQuery`, it used the value on that config field. However, my question is why was it not read, as you said, in the builder? is this an ongoing issue? or it was intentional?

Answer (score 0):

For me this is works

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
            .userDnPatterns("ou=people")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://127.0.0.1:33389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
            .managerDn("ldapadm")
            .managerPassword("root123");
}
```

change "sAMAccountName={0}" to "uid={0}" or whatever your configuration